# Is there a palette for the AuthorTools add-on?

Tags: palettes, authortools

Mathematica still ships with the `AuthorTools` add-on. Is there a palette for that?

(I seem to recall that there used to be.)

Comment: Maybe [this Wolfram Community Post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1911510) will help.

Comment: Some leads: `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications/AuthorTools/Common.m` has a function `paletteNameToPath` that refers to a directory `{$AuthorToolsDirectory, "FrontEnd", "Palettes"}`.  This `Palettes` directory does not exist in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications/AuthorTools/FrontEnd`.  Checked on v12.1 and v10.0 (Mac).

Comment: @TimLaska: No, unfortunately that does not help. The docs show an Export Cells palette, but I find no such. There used to be a palette named, I think, `OpenAuthorTools`, but I cannot find such in the current 12.1 Mathematica.

Comment: According to [this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/May/msg00032.html), `AuthorTools` was considered legacy code even back in 2008 in v6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<< AuthorTools`
OpenAuthorTool[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then clicking on some of the links open up palettes.

> MakeProject, MakeIndex, MakeContents, NotebookDiff, NotebookRestore,
>   Paginate, ExportCells, InsertValue, SetPrintingOptions

open for me (v12.1 Mac), the rest don't.  I have no idea if they're actually functional though!

Comment: Works exactly that way for me, too. It would still be handier to have a single palette `OpenAuthorTools`.

Comment: Note that the individual palettes are (on macOS) in folder `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications/AuthorTools/FrontEnd/TextResources` and so can individually be added to the Palettes menu item using InstallPalette there.

Comment: This is very helpful but more help is needed for the best way to use this. The documentation is obscure. I have some long documents which need the table of contents to have page numbers but cannot seem to make that work (12.3).

Comment: @NigelKg Sorry, I have no idea, just found that by poking around.  You should open a new question on "how to use AuthorTools" to get more eyeballs on this!